# Why won't calibre read the metadata on a recreated .epub file?

Tags: go, zip, unzip, epub, calibre

I am writing a program that takes an .epub file, unzips it, edits the `content.opt` file to add custom metadata, then zip the contents to create a new .epub file. I am using calibre as both my e-reader and my .epub editor, since calibre makes it very easy to edit both the metadata for an .epub as well as the contents of an .epub file.

I am able to successfully create a new .epub file. I have tested this new file can be read both with calibre and my Kobo e-reader.

However, none of the metadata from the original .epub file transfers over to the new .epub file. Additionally I am unable to edit the .epub file in calibre. When I try I get the error "No META-INF/container.xml in epub". I have tried using multiple .epub files and I get the same results and errors.

Unzipped, the contents of the original .epub file is as follows:

```
META/INF
  ↳container.xml
content.opf
mimetype
pages_styles.css
[title]_split_000.xhtml
[title]_split_001.xhtml
.....
[title]_split_012.xhtml
[title]_split_013.xhtml
stylesheet.css
toc.ncx
```

The unzipped directory for the newly created .epub file is identical to the original. Running `diff -r -q /[title]_original /[title]_recreated` produces no output, which would indicate they are in fact identical. So I am unsure how calibre can read one file and not read another. The error seems to indicate that calibre is somehow unable to find the META-INF/container.xml file, which is used to tell an e-reader where metadata is being stored in the directory.

Note: I am not editing any content for the original .epub during the unzipping or zipping process until I am able to figure out what is happening.

I am running the command `go run main.go zip.go` in the directory with the two go files and the .epub file [title]:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
// "log"
// "strings"
)

type FileLocations struct {
    src  string
    ext  string
    dest string
}

func main() {

    fileName := "[title]"
    temp := FileLocations{
        src:  fileName,
        ext:  ".epub",
        dest: fileName,
    }

    // Unzip the zip/epub file
    UnzipHelper(temp.src, temp.ext, temp.dest)

    // Zip the modified directory
    ZipHelper(temp.src, temp.ext)
}

func UnzipHelper(src string, ext string, dest string) error {
    _, err := Unzip(src, ext, dest)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func ZipHelper(src string, ext string) error {
    err := Zip(src, ext)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

**zip.go**

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func Unzip(src string, ext string, dest string) ([]string, error) {

    file := src + ext

    var filenames []string

    r, err := zip.OpenReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        return filenames, err
    }
    defer r.Close()

    for _, f := range r.File {

        // Store filename/path for returning and using later on
        fpath := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)

        // Check for ZipSlip
        if !strings.HasPrefix(fpath, filepath.Clean(dest)+string(os.PathSeparator)) {
            return filenames, fmt.Errorf("%s: illegal file path", fpath)
        }

        filenames = append(filenames, fpath)

        if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            // Make Folder
            os.MkdirAll(fpath, os.ModePerm)
            continue
        }

        // Make File
        if err = os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(fpath), os.ModePerm); err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }

        outFile, err := os.OpenFile(fpath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }

        rc, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(outFile, rc)

        // Close the file without defer to close before next iteration of loop
        outFile.Close()
        rc.Close()

        if err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }
    }

    // Remove zip file so it can be recreated later
    os.Remove(file)

    return filenames, nil
}

func Zip(filename string, ext string) error {
    // Creates .epub file
    file, err := os.Create(filename + ext)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("os.Create(filename) error: ", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w := zip.NewWriter(file)
    defer w.Close()

    walker := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        fmt.Println("Crawling: " + path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()

        f, err := w.Create(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(f, file)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }

    err = filepath.Walk(filename, walker)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("filepath.Walk error: ", err)
    }
    return err
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Adrian I have added my code to reproduce the issue- thank you for taking a look

Comment: It looks like all this does is unzip it and then zip it up again, nothing in the code looks like it would be modifying any metadata in any way.

Comment: @Adrian correct- right now I am not modifying the metadata because even without editing the metadata I am unable to view the metadata on the rezipped files when opening the epub in calibre. Once I started having that issue I removed the metadata-editing section of my code to confirm that was not the issue; it was not, since with just the above code I am having the problem outlined in my post.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, I misunderstood. On re-reading, if the output ZIP still contains the file at the correct path, I'd have to guess it's something to do with the file info - maybe the file mode isn't being preserved correctly?

Comment: "I am running the command go run main.go zip.go" -- don't do this. Never do this. You should literally never run `go run <file>.go`.  Build packages, not files.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a month late, but I ran into the same issue and realized I was zipping the folder holding the epub contents, instead of contents *inside* the folder.

When you zip the folder, the resulting .zip file will follow the same directory structure, so you'll have a subfolder holding the actual ebook contents. The reason you're getting this error is because the META-INF is inside this subfolder instead of at the root.

Example: if you have the contents of your epub in a folder called temp_files, when you zip this folder the file structure will be as follows:

```
+ your_zipped_file.zip
    + temp_files
        - META-INF
        - OEBPS
        - mimetype
```

When it should be:

```
+ your_zipped_file.zip
    -META-INF
    -OEBPS
    -mimetype
```

(english is not my first language so forgive any mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `container.xml` is located in the subfolder, so the issue is most likely caused by incorrect directory processing.
Documentation on `zip` package states that you can create a directory instead of a file by adding a trailing slash to the name (https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#Writer.Create)
Have you tried this approach?